# Diamagnetic materials with negative susceptibility?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, magnetostatics, dipole-moment

I have been learning about magnetostatics, and from reading about the existence of diamagnetic, paramagnetic and ferromagnetic materials I was under the impression that a limiting value for magnetic suscpetibility would be -1. In this case, the material would be acting to completely cancel out the applied magnetic field H so that the magnetic flux density within it B would be zero.

On looking up a table  [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.gemstonemagnetism.com/uploads/Magnetic_Susceptibilities_of_the_Elements.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwix6NSd7LjXAhXR26QKHVeqAOwQFggmMAA&usg=AOvVaw00vBDVbIUJ6TQulHBHeWiT), I was shocked to see that magnetic susvupetobiltiies can greatly exceed -1! I don't quite understand how a material could produce a B field within it that goes against the applied H field. If I consider incremental changes, then I can imagine applying a H field such that  the B field inside the material is initially aligned with H, and this causes electron motion or other dipole- cre0ating mechanisms to create opposing dipoles to counteract the applied field. But a magnetic susceptibility exceeding -1 means that at some point, the net B field within the material is going against the applied external H field . And if I increase the applied external H field even more, the internal B field will become even more negative. It seems to me like the material is behaving in the same way I  two contrasting cases. In the first case when the H is just being.applied, the net field B field within the material is aligned with H and the dipoles induced are aligned against H. But once the limiting case is met where the B field within is now opposing the applied H field, now increasing the H field and thus the opposing B field within the material leads to more negatively aligned dipoles with respect to the external H field, so now the dipoles are forming *aligned * with the strengthening B field within! Of course the only thing 'information' that the region's within the material have access to is the B field within the material itself. I just cannot seem to motivate how the magnetic susceptibility can be less than -1. Perhaps my intuition is being erroneously guided by the concept of conservation of energy and how in electrostatics I don't think the dipoles can be induced against the applied field for the reason of energy conservation. I know these principles don't apply for magnetism, but maybe it is contributing to my confusion.

Comment: Please consider breaking up the wall of text into smaller paragraphs.

Comment: "susvupetobiltiies" is quite possibly the most amazing typo I've ever seen.

Comment: If you want to look for more online, google "giant diamagnetism"